# Adding captions to solr XML exampledocs

Tags: solr

I want to add a caption to some of the XML files in the `exampledocs` directory.  For example, the `manufacturers.xml` file includes 11 rows of data in `<doc>` tags, but nearly every table I see has a caption, maybe something like "Table 1. List of computer manufacturers who provide free recycling for individual consumer purchases blah blah blah...".

Do I need to add a new field name="caption" and repeat that 11 times (it may be very very long ) or are there better ways to add a title in Solr?

Answer (score 0):

if you want a field named 'caption' in you sample docs then yes you need to add them there (there are other ways to add such a field but are much more work, I don't think you would want to pursue that).

Have a look at the [format](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages)

But, just to make sure, if you have a DB and need to index some tables etc, the usual way to go is using DIH, or else doing it programatically with SolrJ api. You know that right?

EDIT: after reading your comment...then you should look at [DIH and Tika](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Tika_Integration)

Comment: No databases, just scientific tables with captions in pdf, excel, word, text, html and other formats.  I can import rows, but wasn't sure about the best way to handle titles which always exist in the files